# How to draw short edges in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

Here is an example of edges I have on my graph.

How do I shorten the edges? Like 2 or 3 times at least. I haven't found the information on [cytoscape's wiki](http://js.cytoscape.org/)

```
{
    selector: 'edge',
    style: {
        'width': 10,
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'line-color': '#9dbaea',
        'target-arrow-color': '#9dbaea',
        'curve-style': 'bezier',
        'label' : 'data(label)'
    }
}
```

[image: Edge example]

Answer (score 1):

The options in a layout affect the positioning of the nodes.  The position of node A and node B is what affects the length of edge AB.

Take a careful look at the options in the layout(s) you are interested in, paying particular attention to

- forces in force-directed/physics layouts,
- spacing/compression multipliers in geometric shape layouts,
- bounding boxes in any layout,
- etc.

You may find it easiest to experiment with different combinations of values, as some options can potentially affect the results of others.

The math involved for line/curve lengths is straightforward.  It's just the [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) for (straight) lines proper, and [quadratic Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) otherwise.